# Multiple slf4j bindings even after pom exclusion?

Tags: java, maven-3, slf4j

I have read as much as I can on this and tried the solutions proffered here on stackoverflow and the slf4j faq, but no success.

Here is my console log:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/david/.m2/repository/de/ruedigermoeller/kontraktor-http/3.28/kontraktor-http-3.28.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/david/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.0/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactoryClassStr()Ljava/lang/String;
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.reportActualBinding(LoggerFactory.java:263)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:131)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:108)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:302)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:276)
at org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider.getLogger(Slf4jLoggerProvider.java:29)
at org.jboss.logging.LoggerProviders.find(LoggerProviders.java:33)
at org.jboss.logging.LoggerProviders.<clinit>(LoggerProviders.java:28)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:2163)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:2263)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2227)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2214)
at org.xnio._private.Messages.<clinit>(Messages.java:56)
at org.xnio.Xnio.<clinit>(Xnio.java:93)
at io.undertow.Undertow.start(Undertow.java:97)
at org.nustaq.kontraktor.remoting.http.Http4K.getServer(Http4K.java:94)
at org.nustaq.kontraktor.remoting.http.builder.BldFourK.build(BldFourK.java:115)
```

Here is my mvn dependency:tree output

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ quokka ---
[INFO] uk.co.example:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- de.ruedigermoeller:kontraktor:jar:3.28:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jctools:jctools-core:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- de.ruedigermoeller:kontraktor-http:jar:3.28:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.github.lukehutch:fast-classpath-scanner:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.undertow:undertow-core:jar:1.2.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.4.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.xnio:xnio-api:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.xnio:xnio-nio:jar:3.3.1.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.undertow:undertow-websockets-jsr:jar:1.2.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.undertow:undertow-servlet:jar:1.2.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.spec.javax.websocket:jboss-websocket-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] +- de.ruedigermoeller:fst:jar:2.44:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.19.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.kie:kie-api:jar:6.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.drools:drools-compiler:jar:6.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.drools:drools-core:jar:6.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.kie:kie-internal:jar:6.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mvel:mvel2:jar:2.2.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-csv:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-dse:jar:2.2.0-rc2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:jar:2.2.0-rc2:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.0.27.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.0.27.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.0.27.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.0.27.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.0.27.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.codahale.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.valchkou.datastax:cassandra-driver-mapping:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- net.openhft:zero-allocation-hashing:jar:0.6:compile
```

Here is my pom.xml, well the relevant part anyway:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.ruedigermoeller</groupId>
        <artifactId>kontraktor</artifactId>
        <version>${kontraktor.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.ruedigermoeller</groupId>
        <artifactId>kontraktor-http</artifactId>
        <version>${kontraktor.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.ruedigermoeller</groupId>
        <artifactId>fst</artifactId>
        <version>${fst.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
        <version>${drools.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${drools.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-dse</artifactId>
        <version>${cassandra}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.valchkou.datastax</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.openhft</groupId>
        <artifactId>zero-allocation-hashing</artifactId>
        <version>0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>uk.co.creditswift</groupId>
        <artifactId>creditswift.domain</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have tried excluding lots more jars as well, but the dual bindings with different version that cause the NoSuchMethodError always appear. You can see I explicitly exclude the jar from log4j-core and log4j-api and yet it appears in the trace as being there? log4j-slf4j-impl does not even appear in the dependency tree, so no idea how it is loaded.

I'm out of ideas. Anybody understand this (it reminds me of the version problems in the DLL hell days, yes I am that old).

Comment: Interesting. Is it a stand-alone app or library or what? If it runs in some sort of container, maybe the container tries to load another SLF4J? Although the very idea of bunding SLF4J into kontraktor-http.jar sounds bad enough to me.

Comment: It is a standalone app based around Kontraktor. Yes, not good that bundling in kontraktor-http.

Comment: Can you try to produce an MVCE? Like a small project with a complete pom.xml and some sources just to make it compile? It's hard to go on with what you posted so far.

Comment: I talked with the developer of kontraktor. He has had to override the logging in Undertow in this kontraktor-http module. This included the `StaticLoggerBinder` class. So the easiest path for me was to add the missing `getLoggerFactoryClassStr()Ljava/lang/String` method to his implementation and it all appears to work. That method in most implementations just throws `UnsupportedOperationException("This code should never make it into the jar");` very messy.